# Converting String to Int in C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, int

I'm trying to make a rock, paper, scissors game and I think i've almost got it but I keep getting a 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'. I've looked all over this website but I can't figure out how to fix it. Here's my code

```
    int userChoice = int.Parse(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);


    Random r = new Random();
    int computerChoice = r.Next(3);

    if (computerChoice == 1)
    {
        if  (userChoice = "rock") {

            resultLabel.Text = Convert.ToString("Computer chose Rock too. Tie!");
        }
        if (userChoice = "paper")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Rock. You win!";
        }
        if (userChoice = "scissors")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Rock. You Lose!";
        }
    }

    else if (computerChoice == 2)
    {
        if(userChoice = "rock") {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Rock. You win!";
        }
        if (userChoice = "paper")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Paper too. Tie!";
        }
        if (userChoice = "scissors")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Scissors. You lose!";
        }
    }

    else if (computerChoice == 3)
    {
        if (userChoice = "rock")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Rock. You Lose!";
        }
        if (userChoice = "paper")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Paper. You win!";
        }
        if (userChoice = "scissors")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Scissors too. Tie!";
        }
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `Convert.ToString()` on a `string`?

Comment: This line `userChoice = "rock"` is wrong on a couple points.   First, `userChoice` is an int, and second '=' is an assignment operator (you want the equality operator `==`).  The reason you're getting the error message is because your basically trying to assign a string to an int.

Comment: I can see several problems with your code. First issue is `userChoice` is defined as an `int` and you try to compare to a string in several `if` statements. Second issue is (I'm hoping it's just a typo) is several `if` statements are doing assignment operations and not comparison operations. You may want to use an `enum` to clean up your logic.

Comment: we have no idea how to help you becuase we dont know what `RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue` contains. What does it contain?

Comment: You should point out where you get the exception

Comment: OK I will guess. I suspect that you need `if(userChoice == 1)` etc

Comment: Also note that `r.Next(3)` will return 0, 1, or 2, not 1, 2, or 3.

Answer (score 1):

First off
You need to change all of your equality checks to be `==` instead of `=`.
`=` assigns a value
`==` is an equality operator

```
if(x == y)
```

Secondly
You are trying to compare an `int` to `"Scissor/Rock/Paper"` which is not possible.
I would advise you to create enums that match your values

```
public enum Choice
{
    Rock = 1,
    ...
}
if ((Choice)userChoice == Choice.Scissor) //Or cast anywhere else where you "input" is an int - you can always cast to an enum from an int
```

and compare to that instead of the strings

Comment: While this is not incorrect, this is just one of many problems OP’s code has. If you decide to answer this borderline off-topic question, then at least try to cover them all.

Comment: I am actually answering his exact question "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'"

Comment: this simply changes to a different error (cant compare string with int)

Comment: Or better yet, `Choice userChoice = (Choice) int.Parse(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
    string userChoice = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    Random r = new Random();
    int computerChoice = r.Next(3);

    if (computerChoice == 1)
    {
        if  (userChoice == "rock") {

            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Rock too. Tie!";
        }
        if (userChoice == "paper")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Rock. You win!";
        }
        if (userChoice == "scissors")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Rock. You Lose!";
        }
    }

    else if (computerChoice == 2)
    {
        if(userChoice == "rock") {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Rock. You win!";
        }
        if (userChoice == "paper")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Paper too. Tie!";
        }
        if (userChoice == "scissors")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Scissors. You lose!";
        }
    }

    else if (computerChoice == 3)
    {
        if (userChoice == "rock")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Rock. You Lose!";
        }
        if (userChoice == "paper")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Paper. You win!";
        }
        if (userChoice == "scissors")
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Computer chose Scissors too. Tie!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lets hope the value is actually the string :)

Comment: yes i think so, :) i will like that hehe